# Superset Docker-Init Installation Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, apache-superset

I am trying to deploy Apache Superset in Native AWS. I am having some custom configuration on top of Superset's base image. Per my understanding as part of Superset installation, [docker-init script](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/docker-init.sh) sets up default tables in RDS Metadatastore and also creates default role "admin".

Superset service deployment completes successfully in CloudFormation but when I try to access my service via a browser, I get below error

```
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "user_attribute" does not exist 
[SQL: 
SELECT 
    user_attribute.welcome_dashboard_id AS user_attribute_welcome_dashboard_id 
FROM user_attribute 
HERE 
    user_attribute.user_id = %(user_id_1)s]

[parameters: {'user_id_1': '1'}]
Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

When I look at the logs of Superset Web Server in CloudWatch/ECS Service deployment logs I can see the log statement `"Starting" "Applying DB migrations"` as mentioned in line 49 of docker-init script but I don't see `"Complete" "Applying DB migrations"` which shows that script is not completed and is failing at step `superset db upgrade`. I also see error `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "tables" does not exist` in AWS Cloudwatch logs.

Could you help me find the root cause of this error?

Expected result is: default tables/roles are created and I can access my service via browser.